# How to change 'X' functionality on main window title bar upper right corner from Close to Exit?

Tags: mfc

When I hover over this 'X' button the tip says "Close" and it behaves somewhat erratically closing one or several files that are not modified and prompting to save one or more files that are modified.

Sometimes it takes several clicks of the 'X'  to clean up all the files.  It would nice if this 'X' button behaved like the File Exit menu item.

Comment: Then go ahead and override `CWnd::OnClose` to call your "file exit" method.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while. I remeber overriding didn't work for whatever reason. In the end i just placed some code in the apps destructor to handle file saving etc. Not ideal, but im happy with it.

You can throw up a dialog like this:

```
int nResult = AfxMessageBox("Save changes to Current Job?", MB_YESNO);
if (nResult == IDYES)
{
  m_bClosing = true;
  OnFileSave();
}
```